# postgres 9.6 - jsonb & indexing - poor performances

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning, postgresql-9.6, btree

On a table (used by a django model) I'm using jsonb column `data` to store arbitrary data fetched from a webservice:

```
abs=# \d data_importer_rawdata;
                                        Table "public.data_importer_rawdata"
    Column      |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                      Default
-----------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------
id              | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('data_importer_rawdata_id_seq'::regclass)
created         | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
modified        | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
entity_id       | character varying(50)[]  |           | not null |
entity_id_key   | character varying(50)[]  |           | not null |
service         | character varying(100)   |           | not null |
data            | jsonb                    |           | not null |
data_hash       | bigint                   |           | not null |
content_type_id | integer                  |           | not null |
last_update     | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
Indexes:
    "data_importer_rawdata_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "data_importer_rawdata_entity_id_service_conten_5fcc60bd_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (entity_id, service, content_type_id)
    "data_importer_rawdata_content_type_id_63138c35" btree (content_type_id)
    "rawdata_data_idx" gin (data jsonb_path_ops)
    "rawdata_entity_id_idx" btree (entity_id)
    "rawdata_entity_id_key_idx" btree (entity_id_key)
    "rawdata_service_idx" btree (service)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "data_importer_rawdat_content_type_id_63138c35_fk_django_co" FOREIGN KEY (content_type_id) REFERENCES django_content_type(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

records are > 1M.

However, despite various indexing strategies (followed this blog post:

http://bitnine.net/blog-postgresql/postgresql-internals-jsonb-type-and-its-indexes/?ckattempt=1

), performances are still poor:

```
abs=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "data_importer_rawdata"."id", "data_importer_rawdata"."created", "data_importer_rawdata"."modified", "data_importer_rawdata"."entity_id", "data_importer_rawdata"."entity_id_key", "data_importer_rawdata"."service", "data_importer_rawdata"."content_type_id", "data_importer_rawdata"."data", "data_importer_rawdata"."data_hash", "data_importer_rawdata"."last_update" FROM "data_importer_rawdata" WHERE ("data_importer_rawdata"."data" -> 'object_id') = '"b8a096da-ff83-47dc-8d22-289ddb46b1c1"';
                                                        QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Seq Scan on data_importer_rawdata  (cost=0.00..142508.65 rows=5155 width=856) (actual time=933.902..8240.465 rows=2 loops=1)
Filter: ((data -> 'object_id'::text) = '"b8a096da-ff83-47dc-8d22-289ddb46b1c1"'::jsonb)
Rows Removed by Filter: 1030908
Planning time: 0.158 ms
Execution time: 8240.493 ms
```

I tried to drop `"rawdata_data_idx"` and use a `BTree` index on a single jsonb key `object_id`, but performances are pretty much the same:

```
abs=# drop index "rawdata_data_idx";
abs=# CREATE INDEX "rawdata_data_object_ididx" ON "data_importer_rawdata" USING BTREE ((data->>'object_id'));

abs=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "data_importer_rawdata"."id", "data_importer_rawdata"."created", "data_importer_rawdata"."modified", "data_importer_rawdata"."entity_id", "data_importer_rawdata"."entity_id_key", "data_importer_rawdata"."service", "data_importer_rawdata"."content_type_id", "data_importer_rawdata"."data", "data_importer_rawdata"."data_hash", "data_importer_rawdata"."last_update" FROM "data_importer_rawdata" WHERE ("data_importer_rawdata"."data" -> 'object_id') = '"b8a096da-ff83-47dc-8d22-289ddb46b1c1"';
                                                        QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Seq Scan on data_importer_rawdata  (cost=0.00..142508.65 rows=5155 width=856) (actual time=951.522..8318.851 rows=2 loops=1)
Filter: ((data -> 'object_id'::text) = '"b8a096da-ff83-47dc-8d22-289ddb46b1c1"'::jsonb)
Rows Removed by Filter: 1030908
Planning time: 0.311 ms
Execution time: 8318.878 ms
```

Any suggestion about that? Not sure that those are the average performances for this kind of task.

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328). Already asked (and answered) here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49551691/330315

Answer (score 1):

For this situation I recommend you create index like the one below;

```
CREATE INDEX ON data_importer_rawdata USING BTREE (cast (data ->> 'object_id' as uuid));
```

and rewrite query like this;

```
SELECT
...
FROM "data_importer_rawdata"
WHERE
  CAST ((data ->> 'object_id') AS uuid) = 'b8b8a275-e397-44d5-b670-84379e5e77c6'::uuid
```

The main idea of casting to uuid is favor uuid data type, which is 16 byte, to varchar(36) which is obviously more.

#### Answer of this question

Although previous approach is faster you probably want only to use index which matches the ORM query. Just create an index like this;

```
CREATE INDEX ON data_importer_rawdata USING btree((data -> 'object_id'))
```

Just carefull about operators; `->` operator returns "json object" as value but `->>` operator returns "text".